# How do I fix the following error? property 'pipe' does not exist on type OperatorFunction

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angularfire2, rxjs6

I wrote the following code following RxJS 6 documentation. I'm currently running angular 5, RxJS 6 and angularfire2 rc.10. The error I get is

```
[ts] property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction<{}, [{}, user, string]>'.
```

This is the code

```
this.companies$ = combineLatest(this.authService.user$, this.filter$).pipe(
  switchMap(([user, filter]) =>
    this.afs.collection("companies", ref => {
        if (user) {
          ref.where("owner.network", "==", user.activeNetworkProfile.id);
        }
        if (user) {
          ref.where("name", "==", filter);
        }
        return ref;
      }).valueChanges()
  )
);
```

this.authService.user$ and this.filter$ are observables.

```
public filter$: Observable<string>;
public user$ : Observable<User>;
```

Comment: Are you sure to use rxJs 6? angular 5 comes and works with rxJs 5. I don't believe mixing those versions is a good idea

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You haven't shown your import statements, but from the look of the error message, it seems you're importing the wrong `combineLatest` function.

RxJS6 has two `combineLatest` functions:

- a pipeable operator: `import {combineLatest} from 'rxjs/operators'`
- a creation method: `import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs'`

You're using the creation method, so the import should from `'rxjs'` and not from `'rxjs/operators'`.

Comment: this worked perfectly, I need to go back and reread how observables work. Any recommended article?